# Need help to format output of SQL Server XML sibling query

Tags: sql-server, xml, formatting

Consider the following SQL Server XML output:

```
<CUSTOMER>
  <CUST_ID>TEST_CUSTOMER_01</CUST_ID>
  <ORG_CODE>MY_ORG</ORG_CODE>
  <CUSTOMER_TYPE CUST_TYPE="RETAIL" />
  <CUSTOMER_COUNTRY CTRY_CODE="US" />
</CUSTOMER>
```

It was generated by the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT 
    CUSTOMER.CUST_ID, CUSTOMER.ORG_CODE,
    (SELECT CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUST_TYPE
     FROM CUSTOMER_TYPE
     WHERE CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUSTOMER_ID
     FOR XML AUTO, TYPE),
   (SELECT CUSTOMER_COUNTRY.CTRY_CODE
    FROM CUSTOMER_COUNTRY
    WHERE CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_COUNTRY.CUSTOMER_ID
    FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FROM   
    CUSTOMER
WHERE 
    CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = 'TEST_CUSTOMER_01'
FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
GO
```

It's required that the output look like the output below. Substituting `ELEMENTS` for the two `TYPE` words in the query above doesn't do it.

How then do I do it?

```
<CUSTOMER>
   <CUST_ID>TEST_CUSTOMER_01</CUST_ID>
   <ORG_CODE>MY_ORG</ORG_CODE>
   <CUSTOMER_TYPE>
      <CUST_TYPE>SHIP_TO</CUST_TYPE>
   </CUSTOMER_TYPE>
   <CUSTOMER_COUNTRY>
     <CTRY_CODE>US</CTRY_CODE>
   </CUSTOMER_COUNTRY>
</CUSTOMER>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best (best in usage **and** performance!) is `FOR XML PATH`. It is very intuitive and easy to define any output you want simply by naming them.

```
SELECT 
    'TEST_CUSTOMER_01' AS [CUST_ID]
    ,'MY_ORG' AS [ORG_CODE]
    ,'SHIP_TO' AS [CUSTOMER_TYPE/CUST_TYPE]
    ,'US' AS [CUSTOMER_COUNTRY/CTRY_CODE]
--FROM   
--    CUSTOMER
--WHERE 
--    CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = 'TEST_CUSTOMER_01'
FOR XML PATH('CUSTOMER')
```

Comment: Wow.. a much better answer than my answer.:)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
select CUST_ID,ORG_CODE,( SELECT CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUST_TYPE AS CUST_TYPE
  FROM   @customer_type CUSTOMER_TYPE
  WHERE  CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUSTOMER_ID
  FOR XML  path (''),TYPE) AS 'CUSTOMER_TYPE' ,(
SELECT CUSTOMER_COUNTRY.CTRY_CODE as CTRY_CODE
  FROM   @customer_country CUSTOMER_COUNTRY
  WHERE  CUSTOMER.CUST_ID = CUSTOMER_COUNTRY.CUSTOMER_ID
 for xml path (''),TYPE
) AS 'CUSTOMER_COUNTRY'   from
@customer CUSTOMER
for xml auto, ELEMENTS
```

Using the above query you will get the result as

```
<CUSTOMER>
  <CUST_ID>TEST_CUSTOMER_01</CUST_ID>
  <ORG_CODE>MY_ORG</ORG_CODE>
  <CUSTOMER_TYPE>
    <CUST_TYPE>SHIP_TO</CUST_TYPE>
  </CUSTOMER_TYPE>
  <CUSTOMER_COUNTRY>
    <CTRY_CODE>US</CTRY_CODE>
  </CUSTOMER_COUNTRY>
</CUSTOMER>
```